# Why is my android app giving an illegalStateException

Tags: android, android-volley

So I am creating an app to send form details and image to a remote server.The details involve some text which I can get from edittexts and image which the user can get from either the camera or the gallery. 
What I am having problem with is the Submit button(bSubmit) which I need to be disabled as soon as it is clicked one time. The problem is it does get disabled but after a lot of time which gives the user a lot of time to click it again and again sending the same information to the server more than once.
But the first time I click bSubmit the same data is being send twice. Is there a specific reason for that?

Also I get the java.lang.illegalStateException.Current thread must have a looper if I try to click the bSubmit button again.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private EditText etName;
    private Button bGallery,bTakePhoto,bSubmit;
    private ImageView imReciept;

    int count = 1;  // To count the number of button clicks;

    private String UPLOAD_URL ="http://some_url.com";

    private Bitmap bitmap;

    File file;
    Uri file_uri_camera;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);


        bGallery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bGallery);
        bTakePhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bTakePhoto);
        bSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSubmit);

        imReciept = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imReciept);


        bGallery.setOnClickListener(this);
        bTakePhoto.setOnClickListener(this);
        bSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v == bGallery){      //20

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i,20);
        }
        if(v == bTakePhoto){        //10

            Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            getFileUri();
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file_uri_camera);
            startActivityForResult(i,10);
        }
        if(v == bSubmit){

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String s) {

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Successfully sent!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, volleyError.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    //Converting Bitmap to String
                    String image = getStringImage(bitmap);

                    String name = etName.getText().toString().trim();



                    //Creating parameters
                    Map<String,String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();

                    //Adding parameters
                    params.put("image", image);
                    params.put("name", name);


                    //THIS is where the main problem is happening 
                    if(count >1){
                        bSubmit.setEnabled(false);
                    }

                    count++;
                    //returning parameters
                    return params;
                }
            };

            //Creating a Request Queue
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

            //Adding request to the queue
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

        }
    }


    //Creates a file Uri for the image taken
    private void getFileUri() {
        //saves the photo just taken into sdcard
        String image_name = "testing123.jpg";
        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + File.separator
                + image_name);
        file_uri_camera = Uri.fromFile(file);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == 10 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){


            //Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            //imReciept.setImageURI(selectedImage);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file_uri_camera.getPath());
            imReciept.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }

        if(requestCode == 20 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            try {
                //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                //Setting the Bitmap to ImageView
                imReciept.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help. I appreciate it a lot.

Also if you can think of anything else that can be improved in the program please tell me. I am still new to android app development. Any help is appreciated.

Edit- Why am I getting a -1 in the question?

Edit 2-

```
      07-17 00:00:23.918  15105-15441/com.example.username.nic_volley E/Volley﹕ [14460] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: The current thread must have a looper!
      java.lang.IllegalStateException: The current thread must have a looper!
              at android.view.Choreographer$1.initialValue(Choreographer.java:96)
              at android.view.Choreographer$1.initialValue(Choreographer.java:91)
              at java.lang.ThreadLocal$Values.getAfterMiss(ThreadLocal.java:460)
              at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:65)
              at android.view.Choreographer.getInstance(Choreographer.java:192)
              at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.<init>(ValueAnimator.java:656)
              at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.<init>(ValueAnimator.java:631)
              at android.animation.ValueAnimator.getOrCreateAnimationHandler(ValueAnimator.java:1453)
              at android.animation.ValueAnimator.cancel(ValueAnimator.java:1057)
              at android.animation.AnimatorSet.cancel(AnimatorSet.java:335)
              at android.animation.StateListAnimator.cancel(StateListAnimator.java:192)
              at android.animation.StateListAnimator.setState(StateListAnimator.java:176)
              at android.view.View.drawableStateChanged(View.java:15988)
              at android.widget.TextView.drawableStateChanged(TextView.java:3659)
              at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.drawableStateChanged(AppCompatButton.java:143)
              at android.view.View.refreshDrawableState(View.java:16032)
              at android.view.View.setEnabled(View.java:6724)
              at android.widget.TextView.setEnabled(TextView.java:1446)
              at com.example.username.nic_volley.MainActivity$3.getParams(MainActivity.java:133)
              at com.android.volley.Request.getBody(Request.java:397)
              at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:236)
              at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:210)
              at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:106)
              at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:93)
              at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:105)
```

This is the error that I am getting in android studio

Comment: Please post your stack trace and indicate which line in your code is producing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You should disable the button as first statement after `if(v == bSubmit){`.

Comment: Thank you. But the main problem is the java.lang.illegalStateException. Can you please help me with that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your button isn't being disabled because you're incrementing your counter until late in the code.  As soon as you enter the onClick() - put this

```
                bSubmit.setEnabled(false);
```

Then it can't be clicked again
If your transfer fails you can then re-enable the button